# Change from graph/Highcharts to maps/Highmaps in my API

Tags: javascript, php, json, highcharts

I have developed a script which enables the display of graphs generated on one server (based on some parameters send by the client) within the website of somebody else's server.

Looks like this:

```
    function drawGraph(selectedID, selectedCountries, selectedYears, per_capita, graphBorder, graphSource, graphDefinition, graphStyle, graphXAxis, renderToGraph, renderToDescription)
    {
        jQuery(document).ready(function() {
            var options = {};               

            jQuery.getJSON("url here", {selectedCountries: selectedCountries , selectedID: selectedID, selectedYears: selectedYears, per_capita: per_capita, graphBorder: graphBorder, graphSource: graphSource, graphDefinition: graphDefinition, graphStyle: graphStyle, graphXAxis: graphXAxis, renderToGraph: renderToGraph, type: "jsonp"})
            .done(function(data)
            {
                options.chart       = data["chart"];
                options.tooltip     = data["tooltip"];
                options.series      = data["series"];
                options.title       = data["title"];
                options.subtitle    = data["subtitle"];
                options.yAxis       = data["yAxis"];
                options.xAxis       = data["xAxis"];
                options.legend      = data["legend"];
                options.exporting   = data["exporting"];
                options.plotOptions = data["plotOptions"];
                options.credits     = data["credits"];

                var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
            }
```

with data["series"] containing data in the format of

```
  {"name": "Switzerland",
   "iso2": "CH",
   "data": [
    [1950, 10923],
    [1951, 20939],
    ...
    ]
   }
```

Now, instead of displaying a graph, I'd like to offer the possibility to display the data as a map. From another project, where I have implemented that possibility (but not as an API), the "series" object looks like this:

```
    series : [
    {
        data : data,
        mapData: Highcharts.maps['custom/world'],
        joinBy: ['iso-a2', 'iso-2']
    }]
```

Now, clearly, the "data" object has to look differently - not one country with multiple years, but multiple countries with one year. And I must indicated that not a graph but a map shall be produced. Plus I need the correct Javascript/JSON files.

But how to I parse the series parameters now? Something like this?

```
    options.series  = {data: data["series"], mapData: Highcharts.maps['custom/world'], joinBy: ['iso-a2', 'iso-2']};
```

Should I do this on the "delivery side" (the php code which generates the data too), or on the client side?

Thanks for any hints. Hope I am somehow clear about what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create just one map (always the same shapes), then you can setup options in JS like this:

```
var options = {
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            mapData: Highcharts.maps['custom/world'],
            joinBy: ['iso-a2', 'iso-2']
        }
    }
};
```

Now, your API won't change at all:

```
options.series      = data["series"];
```